# Manipulate Uniswap oracles

Tags: solidity, uniswap, oracles, defi

Is it practically safe to consume from Uniswap v3 spot TWAP oracles on big pairs like WETH/USDC for example?

I mean, I know it's technically possible to manipulate them, but based on this article, it sounds like it'd be economically impossible to do so: https://blog.uniswap.org/uniswap-v3-oracles

So why would someone do it, especially for small/medium size protocols consuming from these oracles?